# MySQL update query is not updating records

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table containing data as

```
| id  | player  | runs  |
|-----|---------|-------|
| 1   |    A    | 3000  |
| 2   |    B    | 1000  |
| 3   |    C    | 5000  |
```

this is an abstract of large data set which comes from web service in json format, I have to update all the rows with new data using PHP, for just sake of testing I tried to update the runs of all players and SET 3000

```
foreach($json as $indx=>$val) 
 {
     $upd_qry = "UPDATE info SET runs = 3000 WHERE player='$indx'";//Here on each iteration I'm getting current player and Updating its runs 
     $exec_qry = mysqli_query($con,$upd_qry);

     if ($exec_qry) {
        echo $indx.":".$val;
     }

 }
```

this query does not update, any solution to this please

Comment: O Man! this indx is actually player name

Comment: What does `$json` contain? Can you dump it and put it in the question? Or show how you get that variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be:

```
$upd_qry = "UPDATE info SET runs = 3000 WHERE id='$indx'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json as $indx=>$val) 
 {
     $upd_qry = "UPDATE info SET runs = 3000 WHERE player='".$indx."'";//Here on each iteration I'm getting current player and Updating its runs 
     $exec_qry = mysqli_query($con,$upd_qry);

     if ($exec_qry) {
        echo $indx.":".$val;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use prepared statements...?

Comment: Just print `$indx` variable value..
Or Whole query

Comment: What exactly did you change...? Having `WHERE player='".$indx."'"` and `WHERE player='$indx'"` is **exactly** the same. Or did you change something else I can't see (which is also why an *explanation* to *every* answer is a great thing!)

Comment: @Sagar What "yes"? As far as I can see, you don't change anything. Concating like that makes no difference. You should add some text to your answer to explain what you changed - and why, because I honestly can't see any difference.

Comment: @Qirel You can check my comment above??
Just print $indx variable value.. Or Whole query
I think everything is fine here

Comment: He just putting wrong column name or value of specific column to another column

Comment: @Sagar Without any text to support and explain it, your answer makes little sense. And from what I can see, you don't actually change anything that matters. If you add some text to explain what you changed and why, that'd help (not just me or OP, but future readers of this question as well).

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like this:

```
$upd_qry = "UPDATE info SET runs = 3000 WHERE player=$indx ";
```

There is a difference in the '' and "". The single quote as represent as string, You have to echo the query as well, so you have check the difference.